# Simple JSON php request iPhone

Tags: php, mysql, ios, iphone, json

i want to step into the mySQL, JSON iPhone world. I set up a simple weather station with my Arduino and send the temperature to my MySQL database. I created a php file on my server.

When i open the file in Safari it looks like this:

```
{"weatherstation":[{"location":"indoor","celsius":"22.85"}]}
```

Now i want to create a simple Application for my iPhone which displays the temperature.
Can someone help me out some code? I searched here on stack overflow, but the most people are more advanced than i am.

Almost every code began with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myWebsite.com/myPHPFile.php"];
    NSError *error = nil;
```

I would be very thankful if someone could help me to step into this topic.

**EDIT**

Here is some code of my php file. how can i change it to a JSON type? i tried it with

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

But afterwards my php file shows the whole html structure (< html>...< /html>).
do i have to change the html part if i change the content type to json?

```
<?php

...

header('Content-Type: application/json'); 

...

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width"> 
  <title>My Temperature</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
if(!isset($E)) 
{
?>
{"weatherstation":[{"location":"indoor","celsius":"<?php echo $temp;?>"}]}
<?php           
} 
else 
{
  echo $M;
}
?>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please remove html tags it should only have php without space or, tabs or newline characters etc.. See my edit for PHP thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following code you can easily get your json data work

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
     //Call function to fetch temperature

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self getTemperature];
     });
}


-(void)getTemperature{

    NSData *jsonData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myWebsite.com/myPHPFile.php"]];

    if(jsonData){

        NSJSONSerialization *result=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

        //Here you get your json parsed        
        NSDictionary *json=(NSDictionary *)result;

        //Get the weather array from your json
        NSArray *arrWeather=[json objectForKey:@"weatherstation"];

        //Loop to get the values

        for(NSDictionary *weather in arrWeather){
             NSLog(@"Temp for Location %@ is %@",[weather objectForKey:@"location"],[weather objectForKey:@"celsius"]);
        }

   }
}
```

**Edit**

You PHP should look like below you can use this version directly as I have removed leading space from the code

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    if(!isset($E))
    {
?>
{"weatherstation":[{"location":"indoor","celsius":"<?php echo $temp;?>"}]}
<?php
    } 
    else
    {
      echo $M;
    }
?>
```

Comment: hi and thanks for the quick answer. i tried your code but it does not log the "Temp for Location.." line. the code inside the if(jsonData) got executed, but it shows nothing in the console.

Comment: Try set content-type of your PHP to application/json

Comment: i edited my first post. i have some trouble with the php file. it would be nice if you could help me out!

Answer (score 1):

Include [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) in your project, import `"AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"` and
`"AFURLResponseSerialization.h"` in your file and use the following code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] initWithBaseURL:BASE_URL];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username" : @"john123", @"type" : @"login"};
[manager POST:@"data.php" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    NSLog(@"response: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```